# How to create a p2 repository from Apache shiro library

Tags: shiro, p2

I am trying to setup a target definition for an eclipse-based project where I am planning to use Apache Shiro.

Ideally, thus, I would like to get the Apache Shiro jars from a p2 repository, but I cannot seem to be able to find one. Does anybody know if such a repository exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a P2 repository for Apache Shiro with Maven Tycho. Therefore, you have to create a pom.xml that referes to Apache Shiro dependencies in its dependencies section. Then, configure Maven Tycho's P2 Extra Plugin in this pom. This plugin creates the P2 repository for the maven dependencies. [Here](https://github.com/sparsick/generate-p2-repository-from-maven-artifacts/blob/master/pom.xml) is a complete pom configuration example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a repo yourself from within [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_publisher.html). Download Shiro and unzip the bundles into a folder `extractedShiro`.
Create an ant script

```
<property name="dir.shiroBundles" value="c:/tmp/extractShiro" />
<property name="dir.repo" value="c:/tmp/p2Shiro" />
<p2.publish.featuresAndBundles metadataRepository="file:/${dir.repo}"
                                       artifactRepository="file:/${dir.repo}"
                                       publishArtifacts="true"
                                       compress="true"
                                       source="${dir.shiroBundles}" />
```

execute the script with the JRE selection "Run in the same JRE as the Workspace" inside the External Tools Configurations of Eclipse. Resulting p2 repo is then created inside `dir.repo`.